# Search within the current page

Tags: search

I'm trying to place a second search bar, along with the main navigation search bar, on a specific page within a site so that I can search just within that page. Per the recommendation of someone, I placed the following code in my functions.php file

`add_shortcode( 'search', 'tu_search_shortcode' ); function tu_search_shortcode() { ob_start(); get_search_form(); $ret = ob_get_contents(); ob_end_clean(); return $ret; }`

and then added the shortcode [search] to the page.

That worked for putting the search bar on that page where I wanted it, but it still searches the entire site like the general search bar does.

Does anyone know if I can limit the search to that specific page?

Comment: I suspect you'd have to write a custom search query and execute it via AJAX or query strings (and then have the page re-load) - what content is on the page that would require a search for just that page?  There may be a more efficient solution.

Comment: Basically the page consists of about 80 images with titles under or over them that will link to pages with a more in-depth description about specific projects. They want to be able to search those images/titles to easily find what they are searching for instead of scrolling through 80 images on the page.

Comment: Have you considered a “filtering” system rather than a search?  Where you basically take the search parameter (a filter now) and just re-run the query that loads that content buy using a variation of meta queries instead?

Comment: I haven't thought of that, but will look into it. The end goal is to have the user search for what they are looking for and have the results of just that page come up. Your solution might work, but I'm not really sure how to implement it. I'm researching if there is some sort of searchable gallery plugin too that might make this work. If you can expand on your method, it would be greatly appreciated. I'm not much beyond CSS, HTML, and some PHP. And the PHP is really just applying what I find by searching for it and then putting it in my site's code.

Comment: Well basically what you do is, in your template for that page, set up two WP_Queries. One for the initial load, that just loads all of the gallery images, and then another one that loads only the images that fit the parameters of the search/filter.  Easier way to do it is to use query strings (parameters listed in the url like ?filter=what the person searched for") but that will come with a page reload.  Then, checking whether there is a query string in the URL, it determines which of the two queries to load.  So all that's left to figure out is what post data you're comparing.

Comment: In the query you'd use `'compare' => 'LIKE'` and if it's multiple areas you're comparing, then you'd use `'relation' => 'AND'`.  What are you searching for the images?  Titles, tags, categories?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Not sure I understand everything, but I'm going to give it a shot. I am probably going to search the title or tag that describes the photo and the combined photo/title will link to a page with information about the title.